# How to connect to a Qlik Engine API

Tags: javascript, json, api, qliksense

I've been searching on [Qlik documentation](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2017/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/GettingStarted/connecting-to-engine-api.htm) about how to connect a JS code to Qlik Engine, but apparently there is no concrete instructions about that, or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

According, it says that the WebSocket is assignes to a variable in the following declaration:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:4848/app/");
```

Also the documentation talks about the JSON object that Engine API must receive and the JSON that outputs. But, what happens after that? How to I know if it is really connected? Does exists a kind of `ws.connect("?")` function? That's what I'm looking trough the documentation...

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enigma.js](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js) which is a JS wrapper for communicating with the Engine API. Enigma is the official Qlik JS library. Check out the Enigma [basic example](https://github.com/qlik-oss/enigma.js/tree/master/examples/basics) to get started

[qsocks](https://github.com/mindspank/qsocks) was the first JS wrapper (**deprecated**)

For reactive applications [RxQ](https://github.com/axisgroup/RxQ) can be used